# Table seems to be locked when performing large transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are having a huge problem when we have large transactions. I am seeing these issues where transactions are canceled with the following:

> Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

But when I go and look at the process ID, it is just the following: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

Is there a way to have these read committed processes expire or not interfere with active valid processes? Never used to see these before.

We have situations where we send out a large amount of messages.... and at the same time we have delivery receipts come back where we insert into the same table. Usually there is not a problem because the alerts are gone before the receipts come back. But when there is a large alert I think it locks against the inserts.... or the other way around.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

--UPDATE--

So we send out large batches using jobs. These batches consist of messages.

But at the same time we have a scheduled job that updates those messages (that were just sent) with a delivery receipt value. What's happening is we have this second scheduled job running and if a follow on alert is sent, it is deadlocked with the running job (that updates delivery receipts).

The follow on outgoing alert (job) gets canceled.

My question is.... anyway that we could make the updating job be canceled instead of the other way around? We just need to make sure sending jobs are never interrupted or canceled.

I did a trace but it produced 110k lines in a minute. Mostly all the update queries....

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming SQL Server, inspect the deadlock graph to determine which objects are participating, then tune your queries and indexes to avoid the deadlocks.

Comment: So Dale.... would you able to answer this question... I have a table called OUTGOING_TABLE.... and what happens is I insert 40k records into that table.... but at the same time we have receipts (one off) that have to come back and UPDATE those records.  You would certainly suspect locking correct? Would it make sense to make it NON READ COMMITT?

Comment: With regards to your question, I can't speculate without seeing the deadlock graph. That will tell you exactly what and why its happening.

Comment: No absolutely do not use `READ UNCOMMITTED`, it's a really bad idea. To diagnose a deadlock, we need the following info: the two or more queries involved (if part of a transaction then we need the whole batch), the query plans for both (please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan), the full table and index definitions for all relevant tables, and the XDL/XML deadlock graph. Without all this we cannot diagnose this properly.

Comment: Yes. Enable `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` on your database: `ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase  SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON ;`  This greatly cuts down on deadlocks; which is why it is the default on AzureDB.